# Fsck seems to run on every boot

Tags: boot, kernel, 15.10, fstab, fsck

After upgrading to 15.10 today, every startup hangs for around 3 minutes on a screen which reads:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda1: clean, 519049/6807552 files, 7542544/27221248 blocks
[    1.688162 snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.0 CORB reset timeout#1, CORBRP = 0
```

I've tried forcing fsck to run (`touch /forcefsck` and `shutdown -rF now`).

My `fstab` and `blkid` outputs seem to be consistent also. What is going on here? How can I get systemd to show a more verbose log?

Comment: `fsck` just prints that it was run, and detected that the volume is clean, and so no checking was performed.  Whatever the delay is, is happening after fsck, which just happens to be the last thing printed.

Comment: For shits and giggles, `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and check if the boot has any 0's in it

Comment: `/forcefsck` does not work with `systemd`. You can fine tune fsck behavior with kernel command line option http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50772/116970

Comment: Check the output of `systemd-analyze blame` or better `systemd-analyze plot > systemd-start.svg`

Answer (score 0):

I used the boot option

```
systemd.log_level= 
Set log level. As argument this accepts a numerical log level or the well-known syslog symbolic names (lowercase): emerg, alert, crit, err, warning, notice, info, debug.
```

to increase logging, which then informed me that the process could not initialize my `swap` partition. Deleting the existing one and creating a new one solved the issue.